# Are .onion addresses leak-proof?

Tags: configuration, onion-services, deanonymization, ip-address-leak

I want to perform tasks other than web browsing over Tor, for example XMPP chat. I don't want to have to rely on a Tor implementation in the applications themselves, but I do want to avoid leaking my IP address directly or via DNS lookups. (I understand that I'll still be relying on the application and protocol to not disclose my identity/location in other ways, e.g. fingerprinting.)

If I access remote servers using only .onion addresses (hidden services), will I avoid any leaks? In other words, because it's a .onion address there won't be any regular DNS lookups, IP accesses, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `.onion`'s are not exempt from DNS leaks.

Since it's possible for people to run local DNS [gTLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain), DNS infrastructure will generally respect and dutifully perform lookups for invalid domain names. DNS itself is agnostic to the gTLD being valid or not, with [a few exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#Reserved_domains) (for example `.invalid` *should* always fail).

There is an RFC covering `.onion` which should stop DNS leaks from propagating, [RFC 7686](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7686) but it isn't widely implemented yet *(anyone except Firefox?)* and even if it were I wouldn't rely on the implementation of it in some software to stop DNS leaks. Even if the upstream DNS did drop the request because of it's `.onion` gTLD, it has still already leaked:

> A legacy client may inadvertently attempt to resolve a .onion name through the DNS.  This causes a disclosure that the client is attempting to use Tor to reach a specific service. (RFC 7686)

If DNS leaks are a concern you should take appropriate steps to ensure that they cannot happen in the first place, by using a packet filter (e.g. blocking outbound `53/{tcp,udp}` and using Tor's `DNSPort`) or any other suitable means.

Comment: agreed! actually, dot-onions are JUST a naming conventions/protocols... And they're protecting your leaks the very same-best like dot-com's

Answer (score -1):

Tor makes use of hashed TLDs and this makes the DNS query secure but not leak proof , the usr ultimately has to rely on the relay nodes in every case